# Iterating a json with nested objects and filtering depending on attributes values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have the following kind of json file:

```
{
  "trees":{
     "name":"a",
     "age":"9",
     "height":"10",
     "location":"park"
  },
  "cars":{
     "name":"b",
     "age":"3",
     "height":"0.0",
     "location":"park"
  },
  "bikes":{
     "name":"c",
     "age":"110",
     "height":"0.0",
     "location":"park"
  }
}
```

What happens in my react app is that I send this json from app.js to a child component(1) and from there I send single values to another component(2) so as to represent in a row.
Now I have a problem which is I want to send to send data in component(2) only when height!=0.0 which I am not able to do.

This is my component(1):

```
{Object.entries(props.data).map(
  ([key, {
    // name, age, height, location
    ...e
  }]) => {
    return (<tr> <Single key={key} {...e} /> </tr>)
  }
)}
```

I want to filter it such that no data is given to Single component that has height == 0.0

Comment: btw, you have an object, not a [JSON](https://json.org/), which is always a string.

Comment: Actually this was an example the original json has everything in strings but can you tell me how the solutions to this objects is also working on json please?

Comment: this was only a remainder not to use JSON and object/array as synonymes. if you have a problem with parsing/stringify, then you takl about JSON for all other you are talking about some data type from javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first get the pair of key-value using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then filter out the values that you don't want using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Simple

```
const result = Object.entries(obj)
                     .filter((o) => o[1].height !== "0.0")
                     .map([k, v] => (<tr> <Single key={key} {...e} /> </tr>))
```

```js
const obj = {
  trees: {
    name: "a",
    age: "9",
    height: "10",
    location: "park",
  },
  cars: {
    name: "b",
    age: "3",
    height: "0.0",
    location: "park",
  },
  bikes: {
    name: "c",
    age: "110",
    height: "0.0",
    location: "park",
  },
};

const result = Object.entries(obj).filter((o) => o[1].height !== "0.0");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: no need to turn it back into an object, OP is iterating over entries.

Comment: I agree, Great catch 

Comment: what is OP...also there is a need to get back an object since the code where in data is being sent to singledata component its taking an object only>???

Comment: OP is the person who asked the question or I'd say author of that particular question. YUP Edited the answer.